# tensorflow cnn kernel dead

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

'I am a window10 user
I'm running tensorflow in jupyter notebook, perceptron works fine, but cnn kernel crashes.
I also tried increasing the buffer size, but the kernel keeps crashing.
How do I fix it?'

Comment: Can you include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.